# Checkbox having some extra pixel value in Android device browser

Tags: html, css, android-browser

I have customized the html checkbox with applying some css. In that I'm used the checkbox border is 1px solid. But in **the left and top of the border, checkbox having some amount of pixel which is larger than the right and bottom of the checkbox.** While inspecting the element in the device, It's shows the border 1px solid value only.

[image: Checkbox border issue]

How to resolve this issue.?

EDIT 1: CSS used for checkbox:

```
   .rootel {
      height: 12px;
      width: 12px;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid #333333;
    }
    .rootel .innerel.active{
       background-position: 0 -4px;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       float: left;
       height: 20px;
       left: -3px;
       position: absolute;
       top: -5px;
       width: 22px;
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried to reset all other properties that could make this happen? Like `outline`, `box-shadow`, …

Comment: Yes. I have set outline, -webkit-appearenace and -webkit-box-shadow to none. But still the issue exists only.

Comment: Since Android 4 box-shadow is unprefixed. Have you reseted `box-shadow` as well?

Comment: I have pasted the css values in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what issue you have as you don't have put any code so i have tried my self

and interestingly i found no issue

[Checkout here](http://jsbin.com/oyUMIQuS/1/)

I have positioned absolute if i want to apply border to element with div extra applied behind it please note that this can be archived through z-index only other wise check-box will not be clickable

I think there is probability of margin of some 0.03 pixels

In a desktop browser it seems ok but its not solved in android browsers

Comment: I have pasted the css in my question. Please check and suggest to resolve the issue.

Comment: Please check out this. http://jsbin.com/AxadoDI/1. In the class active. checkbox image is placed inside the box.

Comment: It seems no issues there

Comment: In desktop browser, there is no issue at all. The issue exists only in android device browser only. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415412/why-does-a-css-border-look-different-on-android?rq=1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146195/double-width-borders-on-android-devices-with-a-css-pixel-ratio-of-1-5. These links deals the same with no answers resolved.

Comment: So, is this a issue in android browser?

Comment: Ya i found it its can not be possible

Comment: Welcome @Karthick i don't confirmed yet